# Opencart 2 ocMod - выпадающий список категорий

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите, у меня есть код который должен выводить выпадающий список(dropdown list) категорий в сайдбаре, потом подкатегорий и так далее.. Я его засунул в .ocmod.xml вроде оформил, что я не так делаю

```
    <modification> 
     <file path="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[foreach ($categories as $category) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$child_total = 0;]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[foreach ($children as $child) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$child_total = $child_total + 1;]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA['children'    => $children_data,]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA['children_count' => $child_total,]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);]]></search>
            <add position="replace" offset="30"><![CDATA[

    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="box-category">
          <ul>  
             <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?> 
              <?php if ($category['children_count'] > 0) { ?>
                  <h3 class="ccat"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h3>
                   <form name="dropdown_category" id="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>">  
                   <select  style="width: 160px" onchange="jumper(this)"> 
                   <option selected="selected" value="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
                    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
                <li>
                  <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
                </select>               
                </form>
            <?php } else { ?>
                 <li>        
              <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
              <ul>
                <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
                <li>
                  <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                  <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
              <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>  
          </ul>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
    ]]> 
   </add>
  </operation>
 </file> 
 </modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

Начните ваш **ocmod.xml** например так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <modification>  
    <name>Название расширения</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <code>Что-нибудь придумайте</code>
    <author>Имя, мыло, линк на ваш сайт, боевой клич...</a></author>
    <comment><![CDATA[ Лёгкое описание расширения ]]></comment>
```

После установкки **активируйте** его в списке Расширений "Менеджер дополнений"(Extentions). **Очистите** кеш (там же). **Обновите** страницу. Посолить по вкусу, подавать тёплым...